# Vanilla Js - how to show specific image of a slider based on clicked item in previous page

Tags: javascript, html, function, slider

```js
//JS page one
    let box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

    //click event
    box[0].addEventListener("click", fn1);
    box[1].addEventListener("click", fn2);
    box[2].addEventListener("click", fn3);
    box[3].addEventListener("click", fn4);

  //show description at click and hide "click for info"
    function fn1() {
    window.location = 'carousel.html';
    }
    function fn2() {
    window.location = 'carousel.html#2';
    }
    function fn3() {
    window.location = 'carousel.html';
    }
    function fn4() {
    window.location = 'carousel.html';
    }
    
   //JS page two
      /*lightbox code*/ 
      let slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);
      
      // Next/previous controls
      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
      }
      
      // Thumbnail image controls
      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
      }
      
      function showSlides(n) {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      }
```

```html
<!--HTML PAGE ONE-->
    <div id="container">
      <!--one-->
      <div class="box">
        <img title="paint one" class="image" src="images/paintings/1.jpg"> 
        <p class="showText"></p>
      </div>
     <!--two-->
      <div class="box">
        <img title="paint two" class="image" src="images/paintings/2.jpg"> 
        <p class="showText"></p>
      </div>
      <!--three-->
      <div class="box">
        <img title="paint one" class="image" src="images/paintings/3.jpg"> 
       <p class="showText"></p>
      </div>
     <!--four-->
      <div class="box">
        <img title="paint two" class="image" src="images/paintings/4.jpg"> 
        <p class="showText"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <!--HTML PAGE 2 - CAROUSEL-->
    <div id="lightbox">
    <div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img class="image" src="images/paintings/1.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img class="image" src="images/paintings/2.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img class="image" src="images/paintings/3.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img class="image" src="images/paintings/4.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
   </div>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to show the desired image in page 2 Html based on what is clicked in page 1 Html. I know a solution could be to create an HTML page for each photo I want to show on click: I should just change the windows.location of the addEventListener and then in the JS file set the number corresponding to the slideIndex but it would be really good to find a solution without duplicating the pages. I hope I was clear

Comment: I think the best approach would be to use query strings.

Comment: thanks Archit. I have no experience with query strings. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good alternative. Basically in Html page one I assigned an id to each image and in js page one in the fn1, fn2, fn3 and fn4 window.location I added the hash of the relative id eg: (window.location = 'carousel.html#1'). Then in js page 2 I added the following code:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

if(location.hash === "#1") {
  currentSlide(1)
}
if(location.hash === "#2") {
   currentSlide(2)
}

if(location.hash === "#3") {
   currentSlide(3)
  }
  if(location.hash === "#4") {
    currentSlide(4)
  }

})
```

to avoid a possible slow loading in the css file I added a loading gif as a background image in the .image class

Comment: please format your code snippets as code so that people can easily read them

Comment: Sorry Seer, I didn’t know. I think I fixed it